# Need Y Axis values to be Shown as bar

Tags: highcharts

I need to create a graph with y axis values shown as bar as shown in the below image

[image]

Comment: Hi @Sai Ram, Could you describe more precisely what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

you customize using your own html and css grident feature, please have look at below code.

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/0vj27ura/2/`
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I was expecting to achieve it with highcharts config alone